# Salt - Reach all minions in multimaster mode

Tags: salt-stack

I'm migrating salt to salt multimaster.
So in minions config I have my master list, with some multimaster parameters.
I see each master have his connected minions and can talk only with its.
I actually have jobs which send salt commands to my master to run tasks on some minions.
With multimaster I will need to connect on each master and run command if I want to reach all desired minions.

Is there a way to run commands to all minions from only one host ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use syndics and have another master on top.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/topology/syndic.html#syndic

this way the minion will connect to your normal Master/s where Syndic/s is also installed and can failover to any of them. Syndic/s (another form of a special minion) will connect to MoM (Master of Masters) and you can push commands to all your masters. You can also have multiple MoMs which syndic/s are always connected to.

This offers HA for your minions, masters/syndics and masters of masters.

It has some performance impact if you plan to deploy a large number of minions and might require tuning many options.

Unfortunately the Syndic architecture is not officially supported by Saltstack the time that I'm writing this but they welcome community patches. The main reason is because they provide HA through their Enterprise product and want customers purchasing the HA option rather than getting it for free.

The latest is just my personal opinion based on PRs/Feature Requests I have seen being rejected or dismissed to be developed by the Saltstack team. I don't think they made any official announcement about this.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.
In this case, the MoMs don't need to have pillars & formulas whereas minions are connected to syndics/masters ?
Whats is the MoMs config if they just talk to syndics ?

Comment: MoMs have the pillars/states for the syndics and the syndic masters have the pillars and states for the minions.
The syndic is just like a minion to the MoMs. Try to follow the documentation and you should get it done.